# How to config DataSource in Spring through beans in XML instead of application.properties?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I've created new Spring Starter Project using STS.

In pom file I've added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then I've created beans.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="databaseService" class="com.pckg.DatabaseService">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"    value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="username"           value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password"           value="password"/>
        <property name="url"                value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
    </bean>

     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <qualifier value="transactionManager" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and addded to my almost empty web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My DatabaseService class looks like this:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
...
@Service("databaseService")
@Transactional
public class DatabaseService {
  private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    if (jdbcTemplate == null)
      jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }

  public DatabaseService(DataSource dataSource){
    this.setDataSource(dataSource);
  }  

  public DatabaseService(){    
  }

  public String getData(){
        //jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT 1",.....);
        return null;
  }
}
```

and I want to make this config to work. For some reasons those beans aren't seen and I can't start this application.
I've got an exception:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE.
```

and that's because application.properties doesn't contain `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=...` entry and other entries which I include in beans.xml file

When I enter that data and application starts the other info provided in beans.xml is ignored and I believe none of this beans are 'executed'. I want the transactionManager to take part in my SQL queries and currently it's impossible.

Comment: Why do you want to use XML and not use `application.properties`? I don't see anything that wouldn't be possible with plain usage?

Comment: DataSource created from data in application.properties didn't have every setting I put there so I wanted to create a bean with that data on my own, I resolved it creating bean in Java class with @Configuration annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question: Why you creating the XML file, while you are using spring-boot? If you are not intended to use it, and bootstrap your container on your own: simply replace dependencies:

remove:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and check that tomcat-jdbc is in your classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, if you want to overpass the spring-boot related exception [the documentation suggests](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)  to add into application.properties 
`spring.datasource.continue-on-error=false` # Do not stop if an error occurs while initializing the database.

But I cannot assure you that everyting will be working.  To be on a safe side remove any spring-boot related dependency from the project and continue with simple spring, or disregard xml-based configuration in favor of Spring-boot "magic" to bootstrap your container with really nice defaults.

Comment: Instead of getting rid of spring boot I created beans using Java with @Configuration annotation instead of XML; Your answer pointed me I couldn't use XML along with spring-boot so I guess it should be accepted

Comment: You can perfectly well use xml using `@ImportResource`. However creating your own bean isn't needed, at least not if you use the framework properly. So instead of hacking around the framework use it properly.